# update sql slow updating timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9

I have a table with over 500K rows, and I want to update some 
"timestamp without time zone" fields.

```
UPDATE order_update 
SET last_attempt_ts = (last_attempt_ts AT TIME ZONE 'EST') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

But this sql is slow, is there a better and faster way to do this ?

Comment: You say you want to update some records but you don't have a where clause.

Comment: You are updating all 500.000 rows with that statement - that will take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you are converting the timestamp from EST to UTC (even tho the field doesn't have a time zone you want to adjust the times)

Have you tried this?:

```
UPDATE order_update 
SET last_attempt_ts = last_attempt_ts + interval '5 hour';
```

**After running it do a rollback**

rollback;

Because EST have daylight saving which means that for some months you need to add 4 hours or 5, so you actually need to run 2 queries to have the same effect

Hope it helps!

Comment: I get this error : 

ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer
LINE 3: ...E order_update SET last_attempt_ts = last_attempt_ts + 5/24;
                                                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 96

Comment: Well, it is a little faster... ( why is the comments formatted like crap ) ---- 

UPDATE order_update SET last_attempt_ts = last_attempt_ts + interval '5 hour';
Query returned successfully: 5375416 rows affected, 240137 ms execution time.

UPDATE order_update SET last_attempt_ts = (last_attempt_ts AT TIME ZONE 'EST') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
Query returned successfully: 5375416 rows affected, 279018 ms execution time.

Comment: Yes, and that's about the best performance you can get without splitting the query. Keep in mind that you are updating over 5 million rows (not 500k rows): 5375416 rows affected

Comment: Some of the updates I have to make is 500K and the largest is 5Mil, so wanted to test in the large table.